# A moving object $M$ has the same velocity for both the observer $A$ and the observer $B$

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, velocity

Let $\mathbf{u}$ be the velocity of $M$ relative to $A$, $\mathbf{u'}$ be the velocity of $M$ relative to $B$, and $\mathbf{v}$ be the velocity of $B$ relative to $A$.

Then, if $B$ moves away from $A$ only in the $x$-direction, we have
$$u_{x}=\frac{u_{x}'+v}{1+\frac{vu_{x}'}{c^2}}, \, u_{y,z}=\frac{u_{y,z}'}{\gamma \left(1+\frac{vu_{x}'}{c^2}\right)},$$
where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.

Now, suppose that the velocity of $B$ towards $A$ is zero. Then
$$u_{x}=u_{x}',\, u_{y,z}=u_{y,z}'.$$

This leads to the following example:
There is an observer $A$ standing on the shore, observer $B$ standing on a distant ship (don't account for Earth's curvature; the ship is at rest with respect to $A$), and a falling object $M$ that will fall on some place between them. Then for observer $A$, object $M$ seems to fall with the same velocity as for observer $B$ (assume that $M$ does not fall on a place that is exactly between $A$ and $B$).

I think the result is fine in terms of Galilean relativity, but doesn't make sense to me in the context of Special relativity. If $A$ is closer to the place where $M$ falls than $B$ is, then the light from $M$ reaches observer $A$ sooner (in $M$'s reference frame) than it reaches observer $B$. Can someone give me an intuitive explanation of why it is true that the velocity of $M$ is indifferent for the observers in the context of Special relativity?

Answer (score 0):

You are considering how the light from M reaches observer A compared to observer B. In relativity, we deal with reference frames that are associated with observers. Thus, A's reference frame consists of distributed meter sticks and clocks. These are what are used to define events in A's reference frame, not how the light reaches A (what is referred to as lookback, I believe).

Even in non-relativistic cases that would lead to the wrong answer. Thus, suppose an observer is at the origin of a reference frame and there are lamps at x=10 and x=20 miles on the x-axis. If both lamps are turned on at the same time, they would be considered simultaneous events in that reference frame. But the light from the closer lamp would reach the observer first. It would be wrong for him to then conclude that the two events were not simultaneous.